# Azure mobile client hangs when pulling data from specific entity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an entity that looks like:

```
 public class Category : EntityData
{

    [Index("IX_CategoryName", IsUnique = true), MaxLength(60)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId"), JsonIgnore]
    public User Creator { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<UserCategory> Users { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Private { get; set; }
}
```

I had some problems with **Self referencing loop detected for property**. I tried both (both alone, and in combination)

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =      Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;    
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

but without luck. So i went with the [JsonIgnore] tag as you can see in my entity. And as far as I'm aware, azure mobile service doesnt even send nested objects anyways, so there is no reason to serialize that. However when i try to pull the data, the process never returns. No timeouts, no exceptions..

The weird part comes now. If I call the service with postman I get a response.

```
  {
"name": "Food",
"creatorId": "nemtid",
"password": null,
"private": false,
"id": "707cc064-f797-40ee-9ef1-b235e447ff5f",
"version": "AAAAAAAAB9k=",
"createdAt": "2016-11-29T19:58:12.58Z",
"updatedAt": "2016-11-29T19:58:12.58Z",
"deleted": false
}
```

So i guess it's a client side problem?..

I have no clue about how I should debug on this, so if any of you got any clue, either how to debug this, or another way of fixing the Self referencing loop problem, please let me know.

EDIT: 
One side note to make all this even more wierd.
From my client, if i pull all the data there is no problem (neither with the code hangning nor the self reference problem that i fixed with the [JsonIgnore]. So i can pull all data just fine without JsonIgnore) My problem is only occuring with this method request handler on the server:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetSubscribedCategories(string userId, string subbedCats)
    {
        var res = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Users.Select(u => u.UserId).Contains(userId));
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: This is more of an Entity Framework issue than a Mobile Apps issue.  The code in your edit doesn't actually use any Mobile Apps SDK stuff at all.  Suggest you re-tag for a specific Entity Framework audience.

Comment: But the problem is that when I debug the server, I can see that the correct data if pulled and returned. Furthermore if I manually make a request through Postman, I also get the correct data returned.. That is what makes this thing hard to handle..

Comment: Thus you have ruled that the Azure Mobile Apps code on the server is doing the right thing.  You have what I can assume is a custom API on the server that you are calling from your client?  Your code is not complete in this area, so I can only assume.

Comment: That is correct. Im using the ".WithParameters" on my query for the synctable to reach a certain method on my server. A little more technical question. Do you know what the pullAsync method expects from the server? Is it just a pure JSON response that can map to the clients entitymodel, or does the response contain other information aswell?

Comment: The response on a pullAsync() is JSON, but with a very specific format.  Also, it uses OData filtering to do incremental sync.  Thus, you can't just use a WebAPI and expect it to work.

Comment: I'm using the TableController, just trying to figure out why the response I get in Postman doesnt get registred on my client

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem by changing my method return value from IEnumerable to IQueryable.
Furthermore this also fixed my reference loop. So i've deleted all [JsonIgnore] and its still working. Don't ask why